# Extract embedded video source link python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This website has five server streams for all movies, and it shows you how to get the source link from server 2 easily. Thanks for your help, people.

```
def extract_embed_video(self):
        self.clear()
        self.logo()
        print(Fore.CYAN + 'There are 5 servers to choose from' + Style.RESET_ALL)
        selected = input(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + 'choose between 1-5 > ' + Style.RESET_ALL)
        if selected == '1':
            self.extract_server1()
        elif selected == '2':
            self.extract_server2() # //*[@id="oframeplayer"]/pjsdiv[1]/video/source
        elif selected == '3':
            self.extract_server3() 
        elif selected == '4':
            self.extract_server4()
        elif selected == '5':
            self.extract_server5()
```

this is the code as u can see i got the xpath of second stream server